# Change profile picture

Tags: profile-picture, outlook-365

I'm not able to change my profile picture for Microsoft Outlook. It's a school email (365), and clicking My Account says I can't edit some details. Clicking on 365 Profile takes me to Delve, where it says some details are provided by the IT or Human Resource department. But the thing is this: the current profile picture was set by me, not my school! I remember that I faced similar issues last time, but I don't remember how I solved it. Any tips? Since I set the picture, I'm assuming I can change it without contacting the school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the IT Department has changed controls for users since the time you set your photo. This isn't uncommon as organizations are becoming more concerned about any content on their website or related. I realize it is just a profile photo. But it is entirely possible that your IT department has ran into the issue of a user setting their profile photo to something inappropriate. And this forced them to change how much a user can update their profile. See my "SIDE NOTE" at the bottom for more information on what this past issue might have been.

Most likely you already know this information but here is a link about how to update your profile in Delve.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-and-update-your-profile-in-delve-4e84343b-eedf-45a1-aeb9-8627ccca14ba

If you are still unable to update your photo, here is the link about finding your Microsoft 365 Admin.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/who-should-i-contact-if-i-need-to-change-my-information-in-microsoft-365-f0c29a96-723c-4160-9532-d15aebb1dde5

However, this most likely means contacting your technical support team. On the second link I provided, the following information is under **Universities and schools**. *Usually you can find a link on your university site. At smaller schools, there may be just a couple technical people who have admin permissions.*

I realize that my response may not provide you with the answer you were hoping for. But do hope that it helps you as I know how frustrating this can be.

SIDE NOTE: Inappropriate or explicit imagery can mean photos that contain violence or promote it. It could be a gruesome or disgusting image. Or a graphic image of physical trauma. It could be gratuitous portrayals of bodily fluids or waste. Or foul or offensive language, cruelty or gratuitous violence towards animals and/or pornographic images. Or, simply, anything that contained something like a political view. This last possibility has become a bigger concern with organizations the past few years. Note that I'm not implying what you attempt to load is inappropriate. But to give context to possibly why your organization has changed user controls.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. For context, my organization is CTY, a gifted education program by the Johns Hopkins University. They have over 10000+ students, and I wasn't able to find any tech support links. I doubt they'll let me change my pfp though, if this was a deliberate action. Recently they disabled Yammer, which we were using to chat among ourselves, so this was probably done at the same time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This website only allows replies up to 600 characters. Therefore, I will post a few replies as my information is more than that.
I just remembered that it doesn’t have to be your IT department (despite what both Microsoft said on that help page & what I said). Many organizations have one entry point for contact & that department then passes it out themselves to the correct support group. (I can only reply back to you once, so see my additional comments.)

Comment: I’m going to provide you the link to their contact form page. Just fill it out. Their contact form is fairly self-explanatory. Fill out that form and say you would like to change your profile photo but noticed you could not. Then ask them what the process is for you to do so. End it by thanking them, in advance, for their help and that it is much appreciated. If they are truly not the group to help you, they should then tell you who to contact for it.

Comment: Don’t expect a response before the end of next week or a bit later due to we are now hitting the holiday season and those departments may be short on staff because of vacations. 

LINK - https://cty.jhu.edu/contact-us

If you don’t mind, let me know how it all eventually worked out and if this path to contacting them helped you. I’m just terribly curious. It’s the forever state of my brain, always curious and wanting to know more. lol

Comment: OMG thanks so much! I didn't really expect an answer, mostly because it seems like they disabled the option, but also because it really doesn't matter that much whether I get to change my pfp or not. Thanks so much for your reply though - I'll reach out to them, and I'll definitely let you know if something happens. Thanks again  I wish I could double upvote this, but I can't 

Side note: The form is mainly for academic purposes (the subject field doesn't have any option for tech support) and course inquiries, but I'll still try filling it out.

Comment: Don't worry about that form being mostly for academic purposes. When you submit your request, just make sure to note that their IT support contact information wasn't available and that this form is the only one you found for them. Acknowledge they may not be able to help you but ask them to provide you the information of who to contact. Thanks for your reply, by the way! Hope it all works out!

Comment: They replied, although not from the form you sent. I copied that email to another tech support email that I found, and they ended up replying from the second email. Anyways, I've posted their response as an answer below. Hope this clarified things, and thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hey, thank you for letting me know how it all worked out! And I'm so glad you were able to get a response!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote to the oraganization's tech support email, and this is what they replied with:

> Hi Zohan,
> Thanks for sending the screen shots.  Your K12 account is provided for communication about your course while keeping in compliance with US FERPA requirements for minors online.  Add-ons and alternate access to the account will compromise your access.
> K12 accounts are blocked from adding profile pictures.  I suspect you were able to add a pic through an alternate account in Delve, but once the K12 account was added, those permissions were blocked.
> ​Please use an incognito window to access your CTY K12 account through office.com only.  Removing the K12 account from your MyAccount and Delve profiles should restore their previous permissions.
> Best regards,
> Janet Cooke
> Administrative Supervisor
> Johns Hopkins Center for Talented Youth
> cty.jhu.edu/online

So the school really has disabled the option for students to change their profile picture, and I was able to change my picture once because of an apparent bug in the system, which has since been fixed. Hope this clarified things!